# VBA Dictionary class

Tags: vba, dictionary

I just upload Microsoft Excel and my VBA doesn't propose me Dictionary when I want to create my function.

```
Function MyFunction() As Dictionary
```

Should I download any kind of add-in?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following reference to your VBA project:

```
Tools --> References --> Microsoft Scripting Runtime
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use late binding ...

```
Dim MyList as Object
Set MyList = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

Then your Function will need to look like this :

```
Function MyFunction() as Object
```